# How to Sum Time Value in Array

Tags: php

i got this array

```
$total = array('1:00','2:20','4:00','5:10');
```

i try to SUM the total time with this

```
$sum = strtotime('00:00:00');
foreach ($total as $v){
   $sum = $sum+strtotime($v);
}
echo date("H:i:s",$sum);
```

but the result is  19:40:40 should be 12:30

Comment: more possible duplicates in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+sum+time+[php] - please use the search function before asking.

Comment: that's completly different question please see mine , i have multi value array ,the question you gave only for two value and it's not in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This code:

You need to add only the array timimgs then add to todays timings:

```
$total = array('1:00','2:20','4:00','5:10');

 $sum = strtotime('00:00:00');
 $sum2=0;  
 foreach ($total as $v){

        $sum1=strtotime($v)-$sum;

        $sum2 = $sum2+$sum1;
    }

    $sum3=$sum+$sum2;

    echo date("H:i:s",$sum3);
```

Comment: if you marking -1 then requesting you to please explain it.

Comment: i didn't down vote ... but it's error Notice: Undefined variable: sum2 in ... but if i put $sum = strtotime('00:00:00'); it's has false result

Comment: Just add $sum2=0; before foreach (edited above). my result is 12:30:00

Comment: if its more than 24 hours then is not working